# When using multiple realms how do I stop all classes appearing in all realms with 0 instances?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Example:

2 realms: Blue.realm, Red.realm

2 RLMObject subclasses: BlueClass, RedClass.

I create and add a BlueClass instance to the Blue.realm, I create and add RedClass instance to Red.realm.

When I view the realms and their contents in Realm Studio I see this:

**Blue.realm**

BlueClass (1)

RedClass (0)

**Red.realm**

BlueClass (0)

RedClass (1)

The instantiated instances are in the right realms but all other realm classes are added to every realm with 0 contents.

I'm sure there must be a simple fix to that somewhere but I can't find it.

```
-(void)runRealmTests{

NSURL *defaultURL = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL;
NSLog(@"FILEURL: %@",defaultURL);

NSError *error;
RLMRealmConfiguration *redConfig = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
redConfig.fileURL = [[defaultURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"red.realm"];
RLMRealm *redRealm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:redConfig error:&error];
if (redRealm == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    return;
}
RedClass *red = [[RedClass alloc]init];
red.date = [NSDate date];
[redRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[redRealm addObject:red];
BOOL success = [redRealm commitWriteTransaction:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    return;
}

RLMRealmConfiguration *blueConfig = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
blueConfig.fileURL = [[defaultURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"blue.realm"];
RLMRealm *blueRealm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:blueConfig error:&error];
if (blueRealm == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    return;
}
BlueClass *blue = [[BlueClass alloc]init];
blue.date = [NSDate date];
[blueRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[blueRealm addObject:blue];
success = [blueRealm commitWriteTransaction:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    return;
}
```

}

**red.realm after creating one RedClass and one BlueClass**
[image: red.realm after creating one RedClass and one BlueClass]
**blue.realm after creating one RedClass and one BlueClass**
[image: blue.realm after creating one RedClass and one BlueClass]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two separate `Realm.Configuration` instances and create the two `Realm`s using the different configurations that specify which `Object` subclass should belong to which realm. The default config includes all `Object` subclasses in both of your realms, hence the issue.

```
let blueConfig = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: blueURL, inMemoryIdentifier: "blueRealm", schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: nil, objectTypes: [BlueClass.self])
let redConfig = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: redURL, inMemoryIdentifier: "redRealm", schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: nil, objectTypes: [RedClass.self])    
do {
    let blueRealm = try Realm(configuration: blueConfig)
    let redRealm = try Realm(configuration: redConfig)
} catch {
    print(error)
    // handle the error correctly
}
```

Comment: That solves it, thank you. For Objective-C I just needed to set ```redConfig.objectClasses = @[[[RedClass class]];```